# Какой частью речи выступает в предложении слово «там»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, части-речи, частицы

*Не переживай, в твоем возрасте это только начинается: склероз(,) там(,) артрит...*

Понять не могу, разве не нужно обособлять? Вполне убирается, да и по смыслу близко к вводному *«скажем»*. Нигде упоминания про это слово в качестве вводного не нашел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Считаю, что предложение должно выглядеть так:

***Не переживай, в твоем возрасте это только начинается: склероз там, артрит...***

Перед «там» запятая не нужна, потому что это **частица** (частицы, как правило, не обособляются, но, так же как и вводные, могут быть удалены без особого ущерба для смысла). После «там» запятая ставится на основании простого перечисления однородных членов (интонация соответствующая: перед «там» нет никакой паузы, а после есть).

Да, в качестве вводного слово «там» не фигурирует в словарях.

Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC)):

> **II. *частица.*** *Разг.* **1.** Употр. обычно при местоименных словах для придания оттенка несущественности, пренебрежения. *Что-то там пишет, сочиняет. Какие там у тебя дела! Что там ни возражай, а она права. Какие там доходы! Жалеет каких-то там пять рублей. Устала от всяких там разговоров о любви. Сделай там пару бутербродов* (приблизительно).

Здесь нет похожего примера, но обратите внимание на слово "обычно" (то есть не всегда), а тем более на то, что это слово в качестве частицы является разговорным, а значит, легко может использоваться в других конструкциях. Что нам мешает поменять порядок слов и убрать местоименные слова, подразумевая их?
*Пишет там [что-то], сочиняет.

Сделай пару бутербродов там [каких-нибудь]*.

А в Толковом словаре Ушакова ([academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1050838)) есть интересный пример:

> **3.** *частица.* употр. в предложениях или словосочетаниях с разделительными союзами, а также после местоимений и местоименных наречий, преим. неопределенных, для придания оттенка сомнения или пренебрежения (разг. фам.). <...> *«Помимо заката, ей, быть может, добавочно рисуются какие-нибудь там цветки, мотыльки, жучки, какое-нибудь там поле, даль.»* Зощенко.

Можно ведь сказать так:
*«Помимо заката, ей рисуются цветки там, мотыльки, жучки...»*?
Думаю, можно.

Comment: Вот здесь, думаю, похоже: *Мы люди добрые, поможем, чем сможем. **Пеленки там, распашонки**. Не откажем* (Л. С. Петрушевская. Уроки музыки). И тут: *На первый случай, значит, будем мы коллективно на личных хозяйствах названных товарищей шефов помогать, **куры там, козы, свиньи опять же…*** (Анатолий Приставкин. Кукушата или жалобная песнь для успокоения сердца).

Answer (score 1):

http://nskhuman.ru/unislov/slovar.php?nslovo=107174

> Частица. Употребляется при заполнении паузы, возникшей при
> перечислении, внося оттенок неопределенности